# R: tkplot giving error in R

Tags: r, plot, social-networking, igraph, tkplot

I'm completely new to R. I'm working in Social network analysis and want to visualize a network plot. I installed various packages like igraph, ggplot2, tcltk etc..
I have a code as follows:

```
network <- as.matrix(x)
g1 <- graph.adjacency(network)
tkplot(g1)
```

When I run this code, i got following error:

```
Error in structure(.External("dotTclObjv", objv, PACKAGE = "tcltk"), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] invalid command name "font".
```

I tried searching for the answer but could not clearly understand how to resolve it.
Can somebody please help me to resolve this error?

I'm using R on a server through RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

It runs without any problem for me.
Did you installed and load all libraries needed? tcltk and igraph ?

```
install.packages("tcltk")
library(igraph)
x<-read.table("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/mat25.txt", header=FALSE)
network = as.matrix(x)
g1 = graph.adjacency(network)
tkplot(g1)
```

Comment: yes,.. I have installed and loaded all libraries needed as mentioned in question. Still the error is occurring.

As per my survey, it's something to do with "font" over there.. but I could not understand what to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of tcltk you have installed? Because the font command doesn't come in until tk 8.0 [here](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/7.6.html). Install the newest version and check weather the code works.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I've received the same error and simply needed to logoff from my mac & logon again, after having installed XQuartz (which is required by the package tcltk.